# Exception while Deploying ear on glassfish server of amazon cloud

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, glassfish

we are working on java technology and we have created enterprise application in java. we also created the instances on amazon aws. we have the following hosts for our web enterpeise application on amazon

```
SERVER AMAZON= ec2-54-235-50-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com
MYSQL= mysqld@ec2-23-23-65-23.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

we have created the JDBC connection pool on glassfish as follows[image]

when i ping the jdbc connetction pool it is giving the following exception "Class Name is wrong or class path is not set for com.mysql.jdbc.MySqlDataSource".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd ./glassfish3/glassfish/domain/domainl/lib
wget http://mysql.llarian.net/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.zip
unzip mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.zip
mv ./glassfish3/glassfish/domain/domainl/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar   ./glassfish3/glassfish/domain/domainl/lib
```

By this u will get `mysql-coonector-java.jar` file in lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

is mysql connector should be in your glassfish domain lib dir. It seems glassfish cannot find it.

```
glassfish-install-dir\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib
```

Comment: But which command is used to put .jar file in the glassfish-install-dir\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib directory. server is virtual.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the virtual server ?

Comment: Isnt it possible to put the jar to the glassfish installation on the vm ?